# 'free' command shows available ram less than buff/cache!

Tags: 16.04, ram, cache

I have a laptop running ubuntu 16.04 with 4gb ram. I've been using it for about a month now and recently I noticed that the system slows down a lot even with only 3-4 apps running. This is the output of `free -m` with a terminal and gedit open.

```
       total        used        free      shared      buff/cache   available
Mem:    3872         797         842        1971            2232         848
Swap:   4015         141        3874
```

You can see that the available memory is less than cached memory. Shouldn't cached memory be included in available memory? The problem is, when I open some other application, the cached memory size increases instead of giving space to the new app! Here's the output of 'free -m' after opening firefox, document viewer and vscode.

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3872        1391         145        1923        2335         299
Swap:          4015         250        3765
```

`sudo sync; echo 3>'/proc/sys/vm/drop_cache'` doesn't help much.

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3872        1368         239        1923        2265         324
Swap:          4015         256        3759
```

It turns out I can't even open 5 applications on Ubuntu simultaneously. It seems like the 2265mb memory has just leaked out. It's more than half of my physical ram! What can I do about it?

Comment: ok heres the thing, in 16.04 its a bit odd to read, hold on lemme post a answer

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://www.linuxatemyram.com/.

Comment: Yes I've read it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to calculate your free memory try this

(it will print it in MB's)

make a script in bash
add these

```
mem1=$( free | sed 'N;s/\n/ /;N;s/\n/ /' | awk '{ print $8 }' | awk '{ total = $1 / 1024 ; print total }' | sed 'N;s/\n/ /;N;s/\n/ /' | awk '{ print $1}' )
mem2c=$( free | sed 'N;s/\n/ /;N;s/\n/ /' | awk '{ print $10}' | awk '{ total = $1 / 1024 ; print total }' | sed 'N;s/\n/ /;N;s/\n/ /' | awk '{ print $1}' )
mem3=$( free | sed 'N;s/\n/ /;N;s/\n/ /' | awk '{ print $9}' | awk '{ total = $1 / 1024 ; print total }' | sed 'N;s/\n/ /;N;s/\n/ /' | awk '{ print $1}' )
mem2f=$( free | sed 'N;s/\n/ /;N;s/\n/ /' | awk '{ print $12}' | awk '{ total = $1 / 1024 ; print total }' | sed 'N;s/\n/ /;N;s/\n/ /' | awk '{ print $1}')
mem2=$(awk "BEGIN {print $mem2c+$mem2f; exit}")
```

then just do this

`echo "$mem1 / $mem3 / $mem2"`

source: my own code :)

https://github.com/ppigmans/Tool-box

Comment: It printed two backslashes separated by spaces.

Comment: It printed two backslashes separated by spaces.

Comment: odd it works for me, ok try this in the terminal

Comment: ok when I manually calculated it you have 798 MB in use, I did this

in 16.04 you need to add up the `free` memory and the `buffers/cache` memory
and retract that from the `total` memory

Comment: 3872.89 / 890.988 / 2982.3

Comment: Yes it gives around 1 gb. But the problem is that my lappy runs out of ram even with a very small load. And the ubuntu doesn't release cached memory to make space for running apps.

Comment: Can you explain what you're doing?

Comment: Can you explain what you're doing?